# How do I do image color blend in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a png image where some pixels are transparent. The image is all white. How do I use css or javascript to blend the color to another color given its hex code?

I'm looking for something like (this is just pseudocode)

```
<img src="test.png" style="color-blend:#ffea6e;"/>
```

So the effect of this is, the image's (since it was white) new color will be exactly the given color. The pixels that are transparent shouldn't be affected (i.e. remain transparent).

Comment: This might be fancy enough to require a `<canvas>` element.

Comment: How do I use the canvas element?

Comment: Search for yourself.  I've never used it personally, but it's a feature of HTML5 that allows JavaScript to do proper image editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS gradients you could achieve this effect. Just be sure that the blend part has the correct "stops" setting.

A great generator of CCS graidents: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

You can see there are preset gradients that already include transparency to get you started.

The <canvas> element seems like overkill for what you're trying to accomplish and is HTML5 markup, only supported by IE9+ (and pretty much all other browsers ; ).

Comment: Well, since you've looked at the site for only a few seconds try spending a bit more time to familiarize yourself and experiment.

Comment: so it seems I need to add this filter to my image. I tried
<img src="scncolor.png" alt="" style="filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7db9e8', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 );"/>
but its putting the color in the transparent parts of the image, which isn't right. And i'm using IE9.